# jar file directly opening and not installing mobile

Tags: java-me, emulation, series-40

I am trying to create a java me application .
The code is hello xxxx, its simple.

But the **problem is that when I port it to a nokia series 40 phone or an emulator,
the .jad or .jar file opens directly**, but in other series 60 phones like e72 or e63 it installs.

```
public class Hellostackoverflow extends MIDlet{
  private Form form;
  private Display display;

  public Hellostackoverflow(){
  super();
  }

  public void startApp(){
  form = new Form("Hello stackoverflow");
  String msg = "I love stackoverflow";
  form.append(msg);
  display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  display.setCurrent(form);
  }

  public void pauseApp(){}

  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional){
  notifyDestroyed();
  }
}
```

**But I want to install it in phone(and emulator). How can I install it?**
PS: The problem is in code I think. Normally all apps get installed in emulator or phone.
This is not phone problem but some error is in my java file..I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depend on the phone's environment ( operating system ) whether to direct run Java ME application or run it after the installation.

S40 Series doesn't have Symbian Operating system so they are directly opening .JAR files, even you can view .JAD file in S40 Series phones.

On the other hand in S60 Series phones, they have Symbian Operating system and they allow to execute Java ME application only after the installation.

Comment: thanks for reply, but then how people install from OVI/NOKIA[whatever they call it] store? The only way to install on phone is to send it to OVI/NOKIA store and install from there?

Comment: I was talking about all such s40 devices....How apps from OVI store get installed...they are jar files too.The problem with jar file not installing is that all those icons are not displayed.So if I make a jar file then how do I install it? Should some additional steps be taken like signing app or like that?

Comment: you mean you want to display icon for your Jar file ? its easy.

Comment: No, what I am saying is that icon is not displayed until you install the jar...And also jar apps from OVI store get installed then why my jar app is not installing?

Comment: I haven't install any OVI jar file, please give me some link, and for icon you don't need to install .jar file, in my Nokia 3500c , i can easily see icon.

Comment: Ya you are right, icon can be seen. I was installing the wrong app. So I think my problem is solved. Thanks.